# How to use stm32duino control 5110?

Tags: arduino-ide

I want to use stm32duino to control 5110, I use the library http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/download.php?f=LCD5110_Basic.zip

Before, I use arduino pro mini to control 5110 by this library, it works well. But when I use stm32, it fails. Whether this library is not suitable for stm32duino ? If so, which library is suitable for me ?

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you linked to does not indicate it works for STM32 architecture. The display uses SPI, and each architecture has it's own way of implementing such peripherals.

There is this library: https://github.com/KenjutsuGH/Adafruit-PCD8544-Nokia-5110-LCD-library which is a port of the Adafruit 5110 driver to STMduino.

Comment: Thanks, do you know any library of stmduino for Si4463 (RH_Rf24) and Sx1278 ?

Comment: Search in stm32duino forum http://www.stm32duino.com/